# Mapping array into child component using HTML based layout

Tags: arrays, sorting, reactjs

I am mapping an array of objects to props and rendering these in a React child component.

```
<div className="App">
    {projects.map(projectData => <ProjectPreview key={projectData.id} {...projectData} />)}
</div>
```

However, this results in a parent-child output where each iteration results in a new row.

```
<div className="row">
<div className="small-4">{this.props.title}</div>
</div>
<div className="row">
<div className="small-4">{this.props.title}</div>
</div>
```

Using a layout framework such as Foundation HTML columns are defined inside rows

```
<div className="row">
<div className="small-4">{this.props.title}</div>
<div className="small-4">{this.props.title}</div>
<div className="small-4">{this.props.title}</div>
</div>
```

The problem is I need to iterate over the data three times before closing the HTML row. What would be the easiest way to control this layout and iterate/map three titles and then break and continue in a new row, can I use map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because the **ProjectPreview** component renders a `<row>`.

```
// ProjectPreview Component
render() {
  <div className="row">
    <div className="small-4">{this.props.title}</div>
  </div>
}
```

Ideally this should be something like:

```
// App
projectData1 = [
  { id: 1, title: 'title 1', columns: 4 },
  { id: 2, title: 'title 2', columns: 4 },
  { id: 3, title: 'title 3', columns: 4 },
];
projectData2 = [
  { id: 4, title: 'title 4', columns: 6 },
  { id: 5, title: 'title 5', columns: 6 },
];
render() {
  <div className="app">
    <ProjectPreviewRow projectData={projectData1} />
    <ProjectPreviewRow projectData={projectData2} />
  </div>
}

// ProjectPreviewRow Component
render() {
  <div className="row">
    {projects.map(projectData => <ProjectPreviewItem key={projectData.id} {...projectData} />)}
  </div>
}

// ProjectPreviewItem Component
render() {
  <div className={`small-${this.props.columns`}>
    {this.props.title}
  </div>
}
```

This will then give you:

```
<div class="app">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-4">title 1</div>
    <div class="small-4">title 2</div>
    <div class="small-4">title 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-6">title 4</div>
    <div class="small-6">title 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```